# rank of block matrics

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $H=\pmatrix{A_{i\times i}& B_{i\times n-i} \\\ C_{n-i\times i}& D_{n-i\times n-i}}\in M_n(\mathbb F)$ where $\mathbb F$ is a field. Suppose that $rank(H)\geq n-i$ and $XB+YD=I_{n-i\times n-i}$ for matrices $X\in M_{n-i\times i}(\mathbb F)$ and $Y\in M_{n-i\times n-i}(\mathbb F)$. Is it true that $rank(\pmatrix{B \\\  D})$ is $n-i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $XB+YD=I_{n-i}$ shows that the row space of 
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}B\\D\end{array}\right)$$ is $\Bbb{F}^{n-i}$. After all, the rows of $XB+YD$ are linear combinations of rows of $B$ and $D$. The claim follows from this.

---

A general fact: The rows of a matrix product $PQ$ are linear combinations of rows of $Q$. Similarly, the columns of $PQ$ are linear combinations of columns of $P$.

---

Alternatively we can use another general fact (a consequence of the one above): We always have
$$\operatorname{rank}(PQ)\le \operatorname{rank}(Q).$$
Let's apply this to
$$
P=\left(\begin{array}{cc}X&Y\end{array}\right)\qquad\text{and}\qquad Q=\left(\begin{array}{c}B\\D\end{array}\right).
$$
We have $PQ=XB+YD=I_{n-i}$, so
$$
n-i=\operatorname{rank}I_{n-i}=\operatorname{rank}PQ\le\operatorname{rank}Q= \operatorname{rank}\left(\begin{array}{c}B\\D\end{array}\right)\le n-i,
$$
where the last inequality is a consequence of the fact that this matrix has only $n-i$ columns. Thus we must have equality throughout, and the claim follows.

Comment: Can we conclude that dimension of the row space of $\left(\begin{array}{c}B\\C\end{array}\right)=n$ and $rank(\left(\begin{array}{c}B\\C\end{array}\right))=n-i$?

Comment: No. The dimension of the row space equals the rank. And it cannot be larger than $n-i$ when there are only $n-i$ columns.

Comment: I did not say larger.

Comment: So your question about the dimension of the row space being equal to $n$ is a typo?

Comment: @Jarki By your argument, we can conclude that if $X'B+Y'D=0$ for $X'\in M_{n-i\times i}(\mathbb F)$ and $Y'\in M_{n-i\times n-i}(\mathbb F)$, then since dimension of the row space of $\left(\begin{array}{c}B\\C\end{array}\right)$ is n, we should have $X'=0$ and $Y'=0$

Comment: @user108209: No! The inequality $0\le rank{B\choose D}\le n-i$ does not allow us to say anything about the rank, because there are many numbers that satisfy these inequalities. Here we had inequalities $n-i\le rank{B\choose D}\le n-i$, and there are no other possibilities for $rank{B\choose D}$ than $n-i$.

Comment: if $rank{B\choose D}=n-i$ ,then does it implies that there are $X$ and $Y$ s.t $XB+YD=I_{n-r}$?

Answer (score 0):

No, it could be equal.  Try $A = B = C = 0$, $D = Y = I_{n-i \times n-i}$.